# If a deactivated user re-activates his Facebook account, will he receive messages sent while deactivated?

Tags: facebook, facebook-messenger

To add detail, there were three people in a group chat; me, a girl and a boy. Boy deactivates Facebook account and we just ignore it and keep chatting on the group like it's personal chat.

This is all fun and games until I started talking about the boy on this chat and realised my mistake too late. I immediately removed him from the group (he came up as 'Facebook User').

If he re-activates at any point, will he receive these messages?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

No, once an account is deactivated it will not receive any message. After reactivating it will store only that data what all were present before deactivating.

When an account is deactivated it will not searchable and no one can message to that person.